# ExtJS classic - insert chart into tooltip

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, tooltip, extjs6

I'm new with ExtJS, so I don't know, if it even possible. Google answers only how to make tooltips to charts, so...

I need to make a grid with a tooltips, which will be shown when user set mouse on the cell. In that tooltip it need to be a custom information, based on the store of this grid (this part I've made) and a PolarChart, based on the same store.

It needs to be like

```
Name:          first
Date start:    10-02-2017
Date end:      12-02-2017
*It is the PolarChart*
```

I've tried to create a PolarChart inside `tip.update()` in the `beforeshow` function, but it only returns `Object(Object)` instead of rendered chart.

I've tried to render chart with defining it as variable and then render it like `tip.update(var.render())`, but it throw an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of undefined` error.

And even if I try to put property `renderTo` as variable `tip` or `Ext.getCmp('tipID')`, it throws that error.

So, I think, it cannot reach DOM node of the tooltip because it creates dynamically.

Is it some ways to resolve my problem?

Comment: You have to find another way. You could render a window containing the chart (using `showBy` or `showAt`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic [`tooltip`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.tip.ToolTip.html) creation on grid [`itemmouseenter`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#event-itemmouseenter) and [`itemmouseleave`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#event-itemmouseleave).

I have created a small [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29k6) demo.

```
function createToolTip(target, data) {
     return Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
         // target: target.id,
         title: 'Company Overview using pie chart',
         width: 200,
         height: 200,
         items: [{
             xtype: 'polar',
             width: 180,
             height: 180,
             theme: 'green',
             interactions: ['rotate', 'itemhighlight'],
             store: {
                 fields: ['name', 'value'],
                 data: data
             },
             series: {
                 type: 'pie',
                 highlight: true,
                 angleField: 'value',
                 label: {
                     field: 'name',
                     display: 'inside'
                 },
                 donut: 30
             }
         }]
     }).showBy(target);
 }

 Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
     store: store,
     title: 'Company Data',
     width: '100%',
     columns: [{
         text: 'Company',
         flex: 1,
         sortable: true,
         dataIndex: 'company'
     }, {
         text: 'Price',
         width: 90,
         sortable: true,
         dataIndex: 'price',
         align: 'right',
         renderer: function (v) {
             return Ext.util.Format.usMoney(v)
         }
     }, {
         text: 'Revenue',
         width: 110,
         sortable: true,
         align: 'right',
         dataIndex: 'revenue %',
         renderer: perc
     }, {
         text: 'Growth',
         width: 100,
         sortable: true,
         align: 'right',
         dataIndex: 'growth %',
         renderer: perc
     }, {
         text: 'Product',
         width: 110,
         sortable: true,
         align: 'right',
         dataIndex: 'product %',
         renderer: perc
     }, {
         text: 'Market',
         width: 100,
         sortable: true,
         align: 'right',
         dataIndex: 'market %',
         renderer: perc
     }],

     listeners: {
         itemmouseenter: function (grid, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
             //If tooltip is already created then first destroy then create new.
             if (grid.customToolTip) {
                 Ext.destroy(grid.customToolTip);
             }
             grid.customToolTip = createToolTip(item, [{
                 name: 'Revenue',
                 value: record.get('revenue %')
             }, {
                 name: 'Growth',
                 value: record.get('growth %')
             }, {
                 name: 'Product',
                 value: record.get('product %')
             }, {
                 name: 'Market',
                 value: record.get('market %')
             }]);
         },
         itemmouseleave: function (grid, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
             //destory toolTip on mouse out
             if (grid.customToolTip) {
                 Ext.destroy(grid.customToolTip);
             }
         }
     }
 })
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the dream!